# Exported RGB image with Pillow, Numpy in Python is only greyscale

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgb

**Preface:**
Hello, I have a project I'm working on where I take the dominant color of each frame of a video, saving that color (in RGB format Example: (44, 32, 14) ), then exporting these colors to an image where it's x pixels by x pixels.

This is a two part process (two separate programs) where I have first taken the most dominant color of each frame of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hPgjW2ou9E&fbclid=IwAR0FWkyK4hujHyaLLp8L7UE8gvzKs1ncdTsTuC7wOvdApuyPDWikEjcb2kg) video, saved it to a regular text file, where the line terminator is a newline. This is already done and now I have a text file that contains every dominant color of every frame (5169 frames in total), I have checked to make sure that this RGB data that is in the text document is not greyscale, which it isn't, here's a quick few rows as an example:

```
(18, 9, 17)
(19, 9, 17)
(22, 11, 18)
(23, 11, 18)
(24, 11, 18)
(209, 129, 28)
(212, 135, 31)
(214, 140, 33)
(215, 141, 31)
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/YBXwigki) is the full list of RGB colors

**My problem:**

So here is my code for exporting out an image:

```
from PIL import Image
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
import numpy as np

# Create an array for lines of text file
lines = []
# Open file
with open("myOutFile.txt") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        # Strip out new line, turn into Tuple data-type, append to list
        lines.append(make_tuple(line.strip("\n")))

# Convert the pixels into an array using numpy
array = np.array(lines, dtype=np.uint8)

# Create new Image object with non-dynamic 6k,6k image, this doesn't seem to work
new_image = Image.new("RGB", (6000,6000))
# Create image using array
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
# Save
new_image.save('new.png')
```

Like I said before, the image that is rendered out is only greyscale where I know for a fact that there are multiple colors in the data set. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xawBg.jpg) is the output image. It's kind of hard to see so you may want to save and open it in paint or some program where you can zoom in to see the individual pixels.

In creating the Image object I set it to "RGB" mode, turns out greyscale. I've even set the mode in "Image.fromarray(array)" to RGB but still get the same result. The output resolution for the image is 3 x 5169. The 5169 pixels match exactly how many frames I'm getting and if you look, even matches up with when the camera angle changes in the video, which means it's at least working. But my other concern is, why is it 3 pixels wide? If you take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CteBH.jpg) you can see that the 3 pixels aren't even the same color... Does it have something to do with RGB? I only want it to be 1 pixel by X amount per frame so then I can take it into photoshop and create the larger photo.

Also, does anyone know if I can make it export from the X axis (left to right, not up and down)?

Comment: The line `new_image = Image.new("RGB", (6000,6000))` is effectively useless, because you reassign the variable in the line after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a 2D array, `lines` is the y-axis and the tuples make up the x-axis.

That is, with the given data you have 9 lines and 3 columns. Each column has 1 value only, so it can't be a RGB color, just a greyscale value.

If you want a 9 lines image with 1 pixel only, then make sure you put the tuple into an array. The array will make the x-axis and the tuple will make the RGB color then.

Untested:

```
with open("myOutFile.txt") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        # Strip out new line, turn into Tuple data-type, append to list
        lines.append([make_tuple(line.strip("\n"))])
#                    ^                            ^  note these array brackets
```

If `Image.fromArray()` does not recognize it as RGB, you can also define the mode there with `new_image = Image.fromarray(array, "RGB")`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This worked with an Awesome result!!!
https://i.paste.pics/56ea8a53003cde3e7c91f2b8ca45307c.png

Comment: @nmendez: that looks nice